# Tinyscrollbar within Foundation Jquery tabs not working

Tags: jquery

I am having a small trouble with Zurb foundation tabs . I want to have my content within foundation tabs to be in the tinyscrollbar scroll pane. Am using this plugin tinyscrollbar http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ . the content of the active tab is displayed fine within the scroll pane, the others which are not active
Are not working.when i remove the active class from the first tab (which was initially working it does not work)..any help or suggestion plz..have tried this for one week and no success..
This to what am working on is here http://jscroll.kehldesign.com/ (tab 2 is the active one). Tab one not working.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the documentation says otherwise, add the .active class to all of the tabs or add style="display: block" to the other tabs. Both methods work. The reason your "inactive tabs aren't working is because tinyscrollbar can't calculate the height. Adding display: block to the mark-up allows tinyscrollbar to find and calculate the height of the "hidden" container.

One caveat: This doesn't work properly in IE. The scrollbars will work, but the first tab will show the scrollbar of the second tab too. I don't have a fix for that yet.